# How do you parse this string?

Tags: ruby, string

```
/events/3122671255551936/?ref=br_rs&action_history=null
```

I would just like to extract the number after '/events/' and before '/?ref=br_rs...
\

Comment: Writing code would be a good start...

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried already? There are several possible solutions to this problem, of varying degrees of stability and difficulty, and we need to know what sort of situation you're in and what you're capable of working with.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I had tried splitting the string into 3 parts and only using the second but the answer provided was better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why the mad rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split it by the `/` character:

```
irb(main):003:0> "/events/3122671255551936/?ref=br_rs&action_history=null".split("/")[2]
=> "3122671255551936"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method to grab the digits:

```
"/events/3122671255551936/?ref=br_rs&action_history=null".scan(/\d+/).join
 # => "3122671255551936"
```

Comment: This is great until there's a parameter in the query section containing a digit. Queries are easily changed from the server side, often with no notice.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is `str`:

```
x = str["/events/".size..-1].to_i
  #=> 3122671255551936
```

If you want the string:

```
 x.to_s
   #=> "3122671255551936"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the path from a URL. A basic `split` will work initially:

```
str = '/events/3122671255551936/?ref=br_rs&action_history=null'
str.split('/')[2] # => "3122671255551936"
```

There are existing tools to make this easy and that will handle encoding and decoding of special characters during processing of the URL:

```
require 'uri'

str = '/events/3122671255551936/?ref=br_rs&action_history=null'
scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment = URI.split(str)
scheme   # => nil
userinfo # => nil
host     # => nil
port     # => nil
registry # => nil
path     # => "/events/3122671255551936/"
opaque   # => nil
query    # => "ref=br_rs&action_history=null"
fragment # => nil

uri = URI.parse(str)
```

`path` accesses the path component of the URL:

```
uri.path # => "/events/3122671255551936/"
```

Making it easy to grab the value:

```
uri.path.split('/')[2] # => "3122671255551936"
```

Now, imagine if that URL had a scheme and host like "http://www.example.com/" prepended, as most URLs do. (Having written hundreds of spiders and scrapers, I know how easy it is to encounter such a change.) Using a naive `split('/')` would immediately break:

```
str = 'http://www.example.com/events/3122671255551936/?ref=br_rs&action_history=null'
str.split('/')[2] # => "www.example.com"
```

That means any solution relying on `split` alone would break, along with any others that try to locate the position of the value based on the entire string.

But using the tools designed for the job the code would continue working:

```
uri = URI.parse(str)
uri.path.split('/')[2] # => "3122671255551936"
```

Notice how simple and easy to read it is, which will transfer to being easier to maintain. It could even be simplified to:

```
URI.parse(str).path.split('/')[2] # => "3122671255551936"
```

and continue to work.

This is because URL/URI are an agreed-upon standard, making it possible to write a parser to take apart, and build, a string that conforms to the standard.

See the [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) documentation for more information.